# What does poles in unit circles center mean?

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, finite-impulse-response, infinite-impulse-response, poles-zeros

Suppose i have all my poles in unit circle center. What kind of information this gives me?

Can i determine if this filter is IIR or FIR?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $N$ poles at $z=0$ this means that your transfer function has the form

$$H(z)=\frac{P(z)}{z^N}\tag{1}$$

where $P(z)$ is a polynomial. What does this tell you about the filter type? (Hint: write $H(z)$ as a sum of positive and negative powers of $z$).

Comment: If you put it that way, it must be FIR filter, because Z^-13 = 1.

Comment: @eimvs: Not sure if I understand your reasoning, but the conclusion is correct.